# Analyzing algorithms for time complexity

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, big-o, time-complexity

I am analyzing an algorithm and I just want to know if I am on the right track.

For this algorithm, I am only counting the multiplications on the line which have *** in them.

Here's the algorithm:

[image]

1. So I am starting from the inner most line, I can see there are 2 operations there (the two multiplications).
2. Now I am looking at the 2 inner most loops, so I can tell that the `p=p*20*z` gets executed exactly `(j) + (j-1)+(j-2)+(j-3)...1` times. This happens to be equal to `j(j+1)/2`.
3. So in total, since there are two multiplication, it happens `2 * (j(j+1)/2)`.
4. Then finally, the "i" loop happens exactly n times, so, in total, it's `n(2 * (n(n+1)/2))`.

That's my thought process behind this. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: No you aren't. The final result should only contain `n`. You have `j` there.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Would it be n(2 * (n(n+1)/2))?

Comment: Actually, I think that is just a typo as replacing j for n is correct for the derivation he went through there, because n is the largest j. @PragmaOnce yes, although obviously that can be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to do in the original question, but forgot to replace j's with n. Thanks both of you. Does anyone want to post an answer so I can mark this as correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your thought process is correct. You need to replace the j term with an n (n being the largest value j can assume), but that is probably a typo.

Furthermore, you can simplify further from where you are:

```
n(2*(n(n+1)/2))
2*n*(n^2+n)/2
n^3+n^2

=> O(n^3)
```

The last step is because the n cubed term will grow at a much larger rate than the n squared term we can say it will dominate the runtime for large n. Only other point I would mention is that you should perhaps consider the store to p as an operation as well as the two multiplication, although obviously this will not change the simplified big-o runtime.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for simplification!

Answer (score 4):

Computation in this particular example could be simplified if you can find out that all three loops has the same exit condition `up to n`:

1. `i <= n`
2. `j <= n`
3. `k <= j`

Basically third loop would run `n` iterations as well because `j <= n` so `k <= n`,
this mean that complexity would be `n * n * n = O(n ^ 3)`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can obtain the order of growth of your algorithm methodically:

[image]